# Join non-matching lines

Tags: vim, join

I'm trying to join all lines who do not have a match

example text:

```
text Like   
This is text of Line2  
This is text of Line3  
This is text of line4  
Like text  
This is text of line6  
This is text of line7  
Like  
This is text of line9
```

All lines where "Like" is NOT present must join (with space between them)

end result:

```
text Like   
This is text of Line2 This is text of Line3 This is text of line4  
Like text  
This is text of line6 This is text of line7  
Like  
This is text of line9
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following command.

```
:v/Like/,/\n.*Like\|\%$/j
```

Answer (score 2):

First get rid of your trailing spaces:

```
:%s/\s\+$
```

Now here's an idea to join these lines:

```
:v/Like/normal VnkJ
```

Which should be self-explanatory. On every line that does not contain "Like",
enter visual line-wise mode, search for the next "Like" line (it reuses the
previous pattern), go one up and join.

Comment: thank you sidyll, I noted a problem. It doesn't work when there is only 1 line not machting "like"

Comment: The command does not work if there is lines in buffer after the last `Like`-line!

Answer (score 2):

```
:%v/Like/.,/Like/-1j
```

If you only want lines that start with Like, use ^Like instead.
And if you want to get rid of trailing spaces, do as sidyll wrote.

The code means:

```
 % for all lines
 v that do not match /Like/
 ., do from the current line (aka the (not) matching line)
 /Like/-1 To the line bevor the next line matching /Like/
 j join.
```

Since this is easier to understand and looks much nicer, I just add the compleate Version here:

```
$s/$/^MLike/|exec '%v/Like/.,/Like/-1j'|$d
```

It has the following addition:

```
$s/$/^MLike/
```

with ^M being an actual return (done via ^Vreturn)
this line adds a "Like" at the end, just in case you don't have one

```
exec '...'
```

Execs the v-line and protects the last | from being included in the repetition

```
$d
```

deletes the added 'Like' again.

Comment: thank you. it works. Can you please tell me what you've done in this code? ;) I tried to play a bit with the code but it doesn't work when I want to join all lines from "This" till "line7" (because this uses multiple lines?)

Comment: Nikodemus, it doesn't work when the last line has a "like" in it

Comment: It doesn't? I get a perfect result even with a like. That is, the like stays on a line of it's own.

Comment: It doesn't work thou, if there are multiple lines at the end _without_ a like behind ... I investigate

Comment: The command does not solve the issue: lines after the last `Like`-line are not joined!

Comment: Is this still true? I mean with the addition.

Comment: That's right: I was talking about the first command in the answer.  The version that adds a final `Like` is working (yet inelegant).